# Haskell: function iteration

Tags: haskell, iteration

if I have a function that takes a tuple and a list of lists and returns a list of lists

`f :: (Int,Int) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]`

how do I iterate this function using a list of tuples, with each iteration using the result from the previous iteration as input.

ie

```
t:: [(Int,Int)]
t = [(1,2),(2,4),(1,3)]

l :: [[a]]

f (1,3) $ f (2,4) $ f (1,2) l
```

I would like to be able to run this over a long list of tuples.

Thanks!

Comment: This is `foldl (flip f) l`. Also see `foldr f l`.

Comment: @user2407038 works a charm, thanks!

Comment: @user2407038 please at this as an answer (maybe explaining it a bit and linking the funciton) - thanks